# TickLevelFormatter is not working for values 10 20 30 etc in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I'm not sure why its getting difficult. I have data based on date from 2000 to now.
I want to plot the graph for a particular month. Here's my code for Adding Values to Series.

```
SimpleDateFormat sfMonth= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    SimpleDateFormat sfYear= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sfDate= new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    double baseprice=0;
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series=null;
    int currentYear=0;
    for(DayQuote dq:quotes)
    {
        if(baseprice==0)
        {
            baseprice=dq.getClose();
        }
        if(sfMonth.format(dq.getDate()).equals(month))
        {

            int date=  Integer.parseInt(sfDate.format(dq.getDate()));
            if(series==null)
            {
                series= new XYChart.Series<>();
                currentYear=Integer.parseInt(sfYear.format(dq.getDate()));
            }
            double variance=((dq.getClose()-baseprice)/baseprice)*100;
            if(currentYear==Integer.parseInt(sfYear.format(dq.getDate())))
            {
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(date,variance));
            }
            else
            {
                //System.out.println("Adding Series");
                series.setName((currentYear-1)+"");
                lineChart.getData().add(series);                    
                series= new XYChart.Series<>();
                currentYear=Integer.parseInt(sfYear.format(dq.getDate()));
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(date,variance));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            baseprice=dq.getClose();

        }
    }
```

Now, I'm using Linechart

```
LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart=(LineChart<Number, Number>) vBox.getChildren().get(2);
```

I want to show tick on XAxis as 12/Jan 13/Jan etc, So i created a TickLevelFormatter. Below is code for that

```
public class DayTickLevelFormattor extends StringConverter<Number> {
private String month;   
@Override
public Number fromString(String date) {

    return Integer.parseInt(date.split("/")[0]);
}
@Override
public String toString(Number date) {
    //System.out.println("Printed Date"+date.intValue()+"/"+month);
    if(date.intValue()!=10)
    {
        return (date.intValue()+1)+"/"+month;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Issue");
        return (date.intValue()+1)+"/"+month;
    }
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}
```

}

But My Graph is not showing correct label for dates 10,20 etc. Also I'm setting range of XAxis from 1 to 30 or 31 but it still goes beyond that limit and shows 33/Apr (which make me feel very stupid)
Here's My graph

[image]

Please let me know a work around for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will answer your question as there isn't enough code.  My guess is the axis is auto-ranging and it's adding some padding on each side.  There's no 0Mar either.

I can't see where you call setMonth() but I bet that there's some mistake in parsing the date when it's a multiple of 10.

You can solve this by using a formatter of long (actual java/unix dates) and using the format you want like d/MMM.  Or you can set auto ranging to false and set the bounds to 1 -> 31 (for March) and find the error in the call to setMonth.

BTW, there's a suffix feature in the axis formatter, but I've never used it.  You could use that to add month names, if they're all the same.
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter.html